# Adding website logo as the first top level menu item in tb megamenu

Tags: navigation

I am usting tb megamenu module to get a main menu on my site.
Is there a way to add the website's logo as a top level menu item (NOT SUBMENU ITEM)

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for [Menu Icons](https://drupal.org/project/menu_icons) module.

> This module allows you to upload an image in the menu-item's
>   configuration form. After uploading the image, the icon data will be
>   added to the menu link's options array.
>
> When a menu link is goes through the theme layer, it will receive an
>   extra class which by default is used to attach the images as a
>   background image to the corresponding menu item. These class names are
>   also compatible with Nice Menu's.